# How can I consume iOS libraries from MonoTouch/Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to find a straightforward way to consume arbitrary iOS libraries from MonoTouch.  At the moment, I need [this calendar functionality](https://github.com/k06a/ABCalendarPicker), but the question applies to any such component.

I've read the [Xamarin article on creating iOS bindings](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries), but the process of building these bindings looks so complex (and tedious and likely error prone) that I think it would actually be easier for me to re-implement the given functionality in C# from scratch than it would to go through this process.  Creating these bindings would require a deep dive into ObjectiveC, and I'm using Xamarin **precisely so I don't have to do that**.

As it stands, I am torn because I really want the ability to access some iOS libs, but don't have the time to master this process enough to create these bindings.  Is there any other way to access these libraries?

(I wonder if there is or could be any sort of automated binding generator?  It seems to me that 95% of the work is boilerplate translation of ObjectiveC headers to C# idioms, and an automated tool could do this, and then the final tweaking could be done by hand.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can:

- Consume the ones that are already bound: you can find many on [github](https://github.com/), in particular in [monotouch-bindings,](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings) and in the (just announced) [Xamarin](http://www.xamarin.com)'s [Components Store](https://components.xamarin.com);
- Bind them yourself. That does require some Objective-C knowledge. Some tools/scripts [exists](https://github.com/stampsy/monotouch-binding-generator) but, in the end, the manual *by hand* editing is where the Objective-C knowledge is needed. There are [general unit test](https://github.com/mono/maccore/tree/master/tests/bindings) (e.g. for [Touch.Unit](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/touch.unit)) that you can re-use that will dramatically reduce the number of bugs in them (blog post will be coming up soon to describe them in details).
- Convert (or write from scratch) some into C# components;

Comment: Thanks.  I figured this was the answer.  Thanks for all the helpful links.  monotouch-bindings looks really useful and I'd never heard of it.  And the binding generator is what I was looking for, although I suspect it leaves plenty of hand tweaking.  I didn't mean to suggest that I don't want to learn any ObjectiveC, just not enough to write a whole wrapper by hand, when a lot of it is boilerplate.